# Force BIOS recovery on AC connection

Tags: bios, battery

Was replacing the battery in a Dell G15 5515, since the old one no longer charged. However, after inserting the new battery, the laptop refused to charge the battery, claiming that the battery was not identified. I tried power cycling, uninstalling/reinstalling battery drivers, checking the connection, etc - none of which worked, so I tried updating the BIOS. Unfortunately, the BIOS update failed, and none of the recovery options allow me to proceed without a [battery capacity of over 10 percent](https://imgur.com/gb8Y9aw). Any way to force BIOS recovery to proceed anyway? or do I try another replacement battery?

Answer (score 0):

> Any way to force BIOS recovery to proceed anyway? or do I try another
> replacement battery?

In my experience with Laptops and BIOS, there is no way to force this if the machine does not permit it (as yours does not). My own laptops (Lenovo) require a sufficiently charged battery to update BIOS, and I do get BIOS updates somewhat regularly.

Was the battery a proper Dell replacement battery? You may need to replace the battery with  a proper replacement.

If you can get a Dell battery, that is the best choice. Perhaps have a local service shop replace it to ensure all is working.

Try Dr Battery as a decent source for replacement batteries.

[Dr Battery Replacements](https://drpowerglobal.com/)

I have used these successfully for a Lenovo Laptop and charging works properly.

Comment: I've tried two third party batteries, neither have worked - I may try one direct from Dell next

Comment: If you can get a Dell battery that is best (answer now notes this). In my case i had to use 3rd part

Comment: @Andrew - It's entirely possible the inability to charge the battery has something to do the charging circuit within the laptop.  I assume taking it to an experienced repair technician, to diagnose the charging system, is out of the question?

Comment: It's not out of the totally question, just didn't want to be without a computer for an extended period of time, but if nothing else works I'll probably take it to either Dell or a repair shop

Comment: That is probably the best way.  I have answered your question about being able to update BIOS without a battery. I also suggested using Dell, as probably that is the only thing you can do.